# Flutter Dart - How to send a Post Request using HttpClient()

Tags: http, flutter, dart

I am trying to send a Post request to my server using `HttpClient` but I am not sure where to actually set the payload and headers that need to be sent.

```
    var client = new HttpClient();
    client.post(host, port, path);
```

`client.post(host, port, path)`  has only 3 arguments so how do I set the payload to be sent?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Never flutter or dart before but I imagine client has tuples like `client["keep-alive"] = true`

Comment: Which http client are you using?

Comment: @ChennaReddy built in dart library

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[post()](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.5.1/dart-io/HttpClient/post.html) opens a HTTP connection using the POST method and returns `Future<HttpClientRequest>`.

So you need to do this:

```
final client = HttpClient();
final request = await client.post(host, port, path);
request.headers.set(HttpHeaders.contentTypeHeader, "plain/text"); // or headers.add()

final response = await request.close();
```

Example with [jsonplaceholder](https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com):

```
final client = HttpClient();
final request = await client.postUrl(Uri.parse("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts"));
request.headers.set(HttpHeaders.contentTypeHeader, "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
request.write('{"title": "Foo","body": "Bar", "userId": 99}');

final response = await request.close();

response.transform(utf8.decoder).listen((contents) {
  print(contents);
});
```

prints

```
{
  "title": "Foo",
  "body": "Bar",
  "userId": 99,
  "id": 101
}
```

Or you can use [http](https://pub.dev/packages/http) library.

Comment: Thank you, so to add post data `request.add(data)`?

Comment: @UncleVector No, `request.write()`. I added an example to my answer.

Answer (score -1):

```
String url =
    'http://wwww.foo.com';
http.get(url).then((http.Response response) {
  is_loading=true;
  // print(json.decode(response.body));

  Map<String, dynamic> Data = json.decode(response.body);
  Data.forEach((String data, dynamic data_value) {
    print(data + " : ");
    print(data_value.toString());
    //  Map<String,String> decoded_data=json.decode(data);
    //  print(data_value.toString());
    //print(data['title']);
    //print(data['content']);
  });
```

Comment: OP wanted to have the solution with HttpClient and you use the http package.